# Three Questions about Sexual Desire

Tags: sexuality

I am wondering a few questions in regard to sexual desire and Buddhism.

1. Is fantasizing a form of craving and thus worse than sexual activity without it? What are the mental processes involved?
2. How much does a single orgasm, for example, affect the spiritual path? Basically what is the magnitude of the effect?
3. Is it possible that some individuals cannot eradicate lust and should merely diminish it?

Answer (score 3):

> Is fantasizing a form of craving and thus worse than sexual activity
>   without it? What are the mental processes involved?

Fantasising creates further sexual energy that adds to the momentum of the whole process. Mental visualisations and thus sensory pleasure being the 'wanting' component.

> How much does a single orgasm, for example, affect the spiritual path?
>   Basically what is the magnitude of the effect?

An orgasm doesn't effect the path in the slightest. How you have come to achieve the orgasm does. This can be a bit of a grey area for some. Sexual encounters are still possible for a practicing Buddhist but sometimes it's helpful to refrain from sex for a time in order to learn about how your physiology is guided towards the wanting of sex.

> Is it possible that some individuals cannot eradicate lust and should
>   merely diminish it?

If you practice ardently, diminishment will be the first occurrence. It's not helpful to want to eradicate a natural biological process. It will create frustration (dukkha) but it may be a great learning curve if you're well versed in the arisings of your own suffering. Essentially, just work towards learning how it shows itself in your body and actions.

Answer (score 2):

1.-2. Yes, fantasizing is a form of craving and can be worse than mere sexual activity. It simply depends on the reason of why it is done. Such as wanting to release the build up of pressure caused by the accumulation of certain fluids within the prostate gland. The difference being "aversion" instead of "lust".

Fantasizing can be very consuming, addictive, and will incline the mind in a much more forceful manner than the occasional aversion of wanting to get rid of the tactile sensation. Ideally, both should be abandoned.

How much a simple orgasm will affect the path, will depend on the magnitude of craving and clinging, or delight in such things.

3. Yes it's quite possible. If suffering and the path leading to the cessation of suffering is not understood, and not practiced accordingly.

The path is neither indulging nor rejecting, neither passion nor aversion. Unfortunately, it is not an easy path. It is quite simple but it deals with the ultimate, mere intellectualization cannot get us very far. All which is wholesome and  unwholesome must be known and seen directly, with insight. We cannot obtain peace by forcefully suppressing and rejecting.

You can advance at a slower pace, smoothly, or you can go all the way. The choice is yours.

But, for how long will the right conditions for practice remain? The path of Dhamma leads to the complete cessation of all suffering. So great is this reward, it cannot be compared to anything else.

Answer (score 1):

> First Question

Fantasizing a form of craving will make more and more sexual desire which eventually you cannot getaway. After fantasizing mind will ask to feel sound by ears,seeing by eyes,smell by nose,taste by tongue, touch by body. Actually fantasizing is not worse than activity.

> Second Question

So far i haven't seen any Suttra for explain that matter, but i think that habit is huge barrier for spiritual path, whether we believe or not it's kind of a addiction.

> Third Question

Lust will remain until the attain Nirvana, yet only what we can do is just bury it.

Hope this helps.